# Normal wear on five ten freeriders?

Tags: mountain-bike, shoes, wear

So these are my five ten freerider elc shoes[image] and I’ve had them from december last year (2017-present). The pedals on my bike are 2013 dmr v12[image: mine are much more worn] and cleaning my shoes recently I saw that a hole is being worn in[image: right][image: left] and was wondering if that is normal wear and tear?

Cheers

Comment: If shoes condition bothers you (i.e., you feel pins touch your feet or water penetrates and wets your socks), then replace them. If not, just continue using them. Soles of my shoes used with flat pedals and sharp pins are in much worse state. I would not use them for walking any more (it actually hurts in them after a while because foam in those shoes has "deflated"), but for pedaling a bike they are still just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How often do you ride? Short answer, yes this is pretty normal if you ride quite a bit. Shoes designed for use with platform pedals tend to have softer soles to improve grip with the pins. Unfortunately softer also generally translates to faster wearing.

In addition it looks like those particular pedals have a bit of a hollow portion to the pins, whether it is an allen wrench relief or otherwise. (My eyes aren't good enough to tell) I have found pedals that have an indentation or hollow portion in the center of the peg tend to tear up shoes a bit faster as they act like a sort of cookie cutter.

I have sense changed pedals and shoes on my MTB for similar reason. I find using a decent flat bottom skate shoe such as globe, etnies, DC or other similar style works just as well for me and i don't mind the slight difference in grip for general trail riding. Dirt jumping or similar you may feel the extra grip is worth the expense of wearing out shoes quickly.

I have also found Shoe Goo or similar works quite well for extending the use of such shoes once they start to wear. It seems to be pliable enough to work well with pinned platform pedals.

Comment: Agreed - you can choose between durability or grip, they're pretty much opposites.   Flat pedals and harder soles last longest.  Or buy cheap shoes and live with a shorter life span.